# Как обрабатывать все запросы на сайт с помощь лишь одного файла PHP (контроллера)

Tags: php, html, controller

Допустим, клиент запрашивает ресурс (GET) по адресу `http://example.com/hello-world`, или же отправляет заполненную форму (POST) по адресу `http://example.com/signin-form`. Мне нужно, чтобы все эти запросы принимал и обрабатывал лишь один PHP файл — то есть выступал в роли контроллера. И даже если такой страницы не существует, нужно чтобы он всё равно на него «реагировал».

Это возможно сделать и как? Пожалуйста, расскажите про это подробней или дайте ссылку на источник информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё что нужно, это в корень сайта добавить файл `.htaccess` со строчками

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

тогда все запросы будут идти через `index.php`

---

*P.S.* Это касается если сервер - apache. В нём же в настроках должно быть прописано `AllowOverride All`  Если nginx - точно сказать не могу

---

*P.S.2* Стоит заметить, что направдение в один файл не заставит работать полную маршрутизацию на сайте, надо самому разбирать URL и направлять в нужные файлы, т.е. надо чтобы была маршрутизация. Но направление через одну точку входа даёт как раз возможность писать и контроллеры и пр в духе MVC

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное. Я так понял, что у разных серверов разное соглашение. А если допустим нет никаких серверов Apache и т.д, я смогу на своём компьютере с браузером Chrome что-то подобное развернуть без никаких дополнительных ПО?

Comment: @Arkady ну например у php есть встроенный сервер (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.webserver.php) и в phpstrorm тоже такое можно. Но у них есть ряд недостатков. Каких-либо глобальных переменных может не хватать, при отладке какую-то инфу не показывает, ....я точно не помню какие если честно, помню что люди сталкивались с этим, т.к. встроенный веб сервер не до конца так скажем эмулирует настоящие

Comment: А скажите пожалуйста, правда ли, что таким образом код PHP будет работать быстрее, нежели код на Java. Это правда или нет? Во всех случаях PHP быстрее?

Comment: Каждый случай индивидуален, каждый проект индивидуален, зависит всё от множества факторов, таких как железо, ОС, версии языков и желез, используемого доп. ПО (например кэширования), взаимодействия БД если есть, на сколько сложный и витиеватый проект и прочее и прочее. Так что на это никто никогда не сможет ответить точно. А если отвечает - то он либо вас дурит, либо сам ничего не понимает))